# Can I use the present tense "don't" when referring to a past event?

Tags: grammaticality, past-tense

I would like to know if this sentence is correct:

> I **don't love** you anymore after you left me.

I am wondering if it should be "**didn't love** anymore", as the second part after *after* is in the past tense.

Answer (score 1):

No, we can't use don't when referring to a past event. And, "I didn't love you once you left me" doesn't seem right either. In retrospect, use of **didn't** seems right, especially when remembering the day and the way she/he left you, but if I say I didn't love you, it is like saying I never loved him/her. **I stopped loving you** seems more fitting.

Here are a few alternatives you can use:

"I stopped loving you the day you left me"

or

"I learned not to love you anymore after you left me "

Comment: You should address OP’s question, “shouldn’t it be ***didn’t***?”

Answer (score -2):

If you are referring to your current feelings, then *"I don't love"* is correct but should be used with *since* to show the time period:

> I don't love you anymore since you have left me.

If you want to describe your feelings that happened at some point in the past, then you should use the following:

> I didn't love you anymore after you had left me.

Comment: after you have left me??

Comment: @Jim Yep that's a little bit weird. Would you please also share with us what you think about this sentence?

Comment: -1: Like the other comments have said, you alter the end of the sentence without any explanation, and actually make the sentences worse. I agree with your "did" vs. "didn't" explanation though.

Comment: Best avoid mixing simple past and present perfect when the time is understood. I'd rephrase everything: "After you **left** me, I **stopped** loving you"

Comment: I don't know why Tymek's answer has been downvoted; I would have made the same comment.

Comment: @KateBunting Probably because of the "after you have left me" which should be backshifted but even then is still awkward. But also for the verb in "since you have left me" which turns *since* into its *because* meaning rather than its time-relating meaning.

Comment: Present perfect in the first sentence since that action from the past has an effect on the present. 
In the second past perfect, since *leaving* occurred after *not loving*, so my mistake, I have corrected it now.

Comment: Actually I think the "anymore" (which should be two words) is skewing things.